# Protovis map visualization: US+Canada

Tags: dictionary, geolocation, visualization, protovis

I'm trying to make a choropleth map which includes both US states and Canadian provinces on the same map and I'm having some issues dealing with the base map. Protovis comes with a dataset called `us_lowres.js` but there is no good corresponding Canadian dataset...

I have found this SVG map which I would like to use: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/BlankMap-USA-states-Canada-provinces%2C_HI_closer.svg but I want to color it using Protovis if at all possible.

The question is: how can I use the data in this SVG to create a map that protovis can understand? Protovis has functionality for Geographic scales but this SVG is just in whatever linear coordinate system it was drawn in, not lat/lng.

Any great ideas out there? :)